# WordPress Conditionals Giving Me A Headache

Tags: conditional-tags

I have a WordPress Foundation theme I have developed called WP-Forge. [Here is the link if you would like to look](http://themeawesome.com/themes/wpforge) so you can get a general idea of what I am talking about. I have received a lot of questions about how to remove the date, author and comments that appear under the title of posts. So I figured I would make this an option in the customizer.

So I added what I needed to the customizer and it looks awesome. So now I go into content.php and try adding the conditionals I need to make it work:

```
<?php if( get_theme_mod( 'wpforge_meta_display' ) == 'yes' && get_theme_mod( 'wpforge_meta_position' ) == 'under') { ?>
   <?php wpforge_entry_meta_header(); ?>
   <?php if ( comments_open() ) : ?>            
   <span class="genericon genericon-comment"></span> <?php comments_popup_link( '<span class="leave-reply">' . __( 'Comment', 'wp-forge' ) . '</span>', __( '1 Comment', 'wp-forge' ), __( '% Comments', 'wp-forge' ) ); ?>
   <?php endif; // comments_open() ?>
<?php } // end if ?>
```

Basically, as most of you know, the conditional states if you want to show the meta information AND you want to show the meta information under the title, then display the meta. Or at least its supposed to.

So if those two conditions are met then the meta information should show and it should show under the title right? As it stands the meta information will not appear. Did I do it properly?

Comment: Your logic looks fine as far as I can tell. I think your problem is the values of `get_theme_mod( 'x' )`, they are not what you think they are. Have you done a `var_dump()` on these to make sure that you actually have values and if you do, are they what you expect them to be?

Comment: Thanks for taking a look however I do not know how to do a var_dump() - how does that work

Comment: See [this](http://php.net/manual/en/function.var-dump.php). You can, for example, add `var_dump( get_theme_mod( 'wpforge_meta_display' ) )`  in your template. This will print the value of `get_theme_mod( 'wpforge_meta_display' )` to screen

Comment: AWESOME!!! thank you sir. I learned something new and very cool. Thank you. I did what you suggested and everything is out putting the way its supposed to. Oh well I did however come up with a better way of doing what I want to do. Thanks for the help and thanks again especially for my newly aquired tool.

Comment: My pleasure. Yes, `var_dump()` is really very helpful. I abuse it :-). Enjoy